# meteor 1.3 app structure: spltting tasks into methods subscriptions

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, ecmascript-6

This is probably a very easy question for meteor 1.3 knowledgable people.

In the [meteor application structure documentation](http://guide.meteor.com/structure.html) its recommended to split an API into a few files but I didn't see any examples of how to pull them back together.
I'm starting with [Todo React Tutorial: Collections](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/collections) and I'm trying to split `/api/tasks.js` into
`tasks.js methods.js server/publications.js`

I don't know what changes I need to make from the code that was in tasks.js to properly import the code moved to methods.js and server/publications.js

Thank you for your assistance!

Code: http://www.github.com/Falieson/LearningReact/blob/meteor_todos/MeteorTodos_React/imports/api/tasks/tasks.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fairly broad and opinionated topic, so I will try to give a concise answer that relates to matters discussed in the Meteor Guide.

First, I would follow through with the tutorial to get its purpose. To me, it seems that it is not intended to teach you how to build a complex app, but rather to get the hang of React in a basic Meteor project.

**There is no definitive answer** to the question of project structure, as it is fairly opinionated. Some partition by function, others by feature; some like deep nesting and some prefer a more flat structure.

The main theme is that the modules' explicit `import` syntax **makes your dependencies explicit** and therefore prevent the need for guesswork or awkward filenames that loses semantics and makes finding the source of each symbol a non-trivial task.

The app structure tutorial is not complete either and mainly includes guidelines.

Let's assume something like the following simple structure, that fits pretty closely with the use-case:

```
.
├── client
│   └── main.js
├── imports
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── api.js
│   │   ├── api-server.js
│   │   └── module1
│   │       ├── collections.js
│   │       ├── methods.js
│   │       └── server
│   │           └── publications.js
│   ├── client
│   │   └── index.js
│   └── server
│       └── index.js
└── server
    └── main.js
```

Anything in the `imports` directory is not automatically imported. It all starts in the `server/main.js` and `client/main.js` **entry points**.

They, in turn, import the `imports/<target>/index.js`, which is where the app is bootstrapped for each target (client/server).

Since some of the `api` code is server-specific, you would probably want to create a `server-api.js` file or the like that also imports the server resources.

During the bootstrap process, the server's `index.js` will

```
import '../api/api-server';
```

`api-server.js` will:

```
import './api';
import './module1/server/publications';
```

while the `client/index.js` could import `api.js` directly.

Standard methods and publications do not export any symbol, so no need to import them individually, but only the file that they are defined in.

`api.js` will:

```
import './module1/methods';
```

where `methods.js` and `publications.js` will import the `collections.js` file, assuming they need it.

Again, this is a very broad and opinionated topic and there are several ways to structure your project.

Comment: I understand meteor 1.2 pretty well and have made a pretty large app with it. Now I'm trying to learn 4 things large scale app structure for 1.3, this import/export, React, and Mocha. 
Thank you for addressing the complication I was having "Standard methods and publications do not export any symbol .. [import] the file". I tried putting  `import './server/publications.js'; import './methods.js';` into the tasks.js file wasn't enough to make the tasks.tests.js pass. Going to try out your suggestions now.

Comment: Regarding Large Scale App Structure: The research I've done concluded the same as you said - there's no standard, so I figured I'd use Meteor's.

Comment: In the tutorial the tasks.tests.js just imports Tasks from './tasks.js'. Is import {Tasks} from './collections.js' and import './methods.js' duplicate code that I put in both tasks.js and tasks.tests.js ?
My [tasks.js](https://github.com/Falieson/LearningReact/blob/meteor_todos/MeteorTodos_React/imports/api/tasks/tasks.js) and [tasks.tests.js](https://github.com/Falieson/LearningReact/blob/meteor_todos/MeteorTodos_React/imports/api/tasks/tasks.tests.js)

Comment: I think that `collections` is redundant in your structure. `tasks.js` and `collections.js` are 2 ways of naming the files that define the collections, and both are fine (I lean towards a single `collections.js` file where I define all of the collections relevant to the module, and sometimes even use a `lib/collections.js` to define all of the app's collections). Every file is evaluated exactly once (if imported) on each target, so no need to worry about imports duplication. Import what you need.

Comment: Thanks for that final clarification!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. I'm guessing it's about the `import` statements.

In your original tasks file you have

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';
```

You need those to use functions/objects from the Meteor, Mongo and check packages.

You need look at what the code needs. In your `methods.js` file, you use `Meteor` and `check`, but you don't use `Mongo`. So you want to add

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';
```

I also see that you declare your Mongo collection in your `publication.js` file, which is usually not appropriate. A publication should run only on the server, while your collection should be declared both on the client and the server.

So you should move this code

```
export const Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');
```

typically, it would go in the `task.js` file.

In this case, in the `task.js`, as you're declaring a collection, you're using the Mongo object and you need to

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
```

And in your publication, for the moment you just need

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
```

There's still a problem, as you declared the task object using `export`, you need to import it the same way than you import Meteor, Mongo and check, but as your own package:

```
import { Tasks } from './tasks';
```

for files in the same folder than the `tasks.js` file. And

```
import { Tasks } from '../tasks';
```

if it's in a subfolder.

Does this somehow answers your question? If you need more help, please be more specific and/or include some error log.